# How to insert background (picture) elements in a bulleted list, a url to which is written in the neighboring bulleted list

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two bulleted list. One attribute in `data-img` elements spelledli`, url`'s pictures which should be in the background elements of the second bullet.
I wrote here such code, thinking that he runs across correctly, but it seems with each pass he turns to the first element `li`

```js
$(".views").each(function() {
  var bg = $(this).attr("data-img");
  //alert(bg);

  $("ol.buttons li a").css({
    background: "url(" + bg + ")"
  })
})
```

```css
.views {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #ccc;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Убираем маркеры */
}
li.but {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
ol.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  background-size: cover!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="parent-view">
  <li class="views" data-img="http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg"></li>
  <li class="views" data-img="http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png"></li>
  <li class="views" data-img="http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif"></li>
</ul>
<ol class="buttons">
  <li class="but"><a>1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>3</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I know that even `for` is, but how it go through I can not understand ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9tg4eot/8/) :

```
$(".views").each(function() {
    var bg = $(this).attr("data-img");
    var self   = $(this),
    index  = self.index();

    $("ol.buttons li a:eq("+index+")").css(
    "background","url(" + bg + ")"
    )
})
```